# How can I get an ftp connection to stop timing out in emacs?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ftp

I'm using `M-x shell` in Emacs and just connecting through vanilla `ftp` from the command line (bash).

I remember (many moons ago) I came across a script for Emacs that'd keep a persistent ftp connection going for shell/bash/ftp, pinging the remote server every 30-60 seconds and thus stopping the connection from timing out, and saving me the hassle of entering the connection strings over and over.

Is there a LISP script for this task? Or how does everyone else do it?

I use ftp over TLS. My remote shared host doesn't support ssh.

Comment: Nothing. But my question isn't about Filezilla. It's about creating a persistent FTP connection for emacs ...

Comment: `ncftp` might be better than plain old `ftp` in this respect.  It's too many years since I was using it, but it's a nicer client in general.  I'd think you can use `M-x ftp` with either, rather than going via a shell buffer (with the appropriate `ftp-program` and `ftp-program-options` user options configured in Emacs).  Also see `C-h i g (emacs)Remote Files` in case that's helpful.